# Yahoo_Finance Package for Python - Share() does not work anymore

Tags: python-3.x, yql, yahoo-finance

Since today I am experiencing some errors caused by the yahoo_finance package version 1.4.

Here is a code example that is causing the error:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
Apple = Share("AAPL")
```

Results in the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 120, in _request
    _, results = response['query']['results'].popitem()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'popitem'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 123, in _request
    raise YQLQueryError(response['error']['description'])
KeyError: 'error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-44fc1f59aa21>", line 1, in <module>
    Apple = Share("AAPL")
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 178, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 142, in refresh
    self.data_set = self._fetch()
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 181, in _fetch
    data = super(Share, self)._fetch()
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 134, in _fetch
    data = self._request(query)
  File "C:\Users\Julian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 125, in _request
    raise YQLResponseMalformedError()
yahoo_finance.YQLResponseMalformedError: Response malformed.
```

Do you experience similar issues or is this only an issue for me personally?
Thank you for your replies.
If yes - what are potential fixes for this issue?

Comment: The same problem.
It's try to get data from yahoo.finance.quotes table, but it doesn't exist now.
Another table pm.finance need in permissions.

Comment: Do you have a suitable workaround / Know about a fix that allows accessing the data in a different way?